# css - div parent not ok , height remains 0px

Tags: css

ALL COMPONENTS ARE DISPLAYED OK. BUT WHEN I PRESS F12 AND HOVER OVER NAVBAR-LEFT, it's height is that of 0px. I think I need to solve this by placing a small div with class clear somewhere, but I don't know where exactly!

```
<div class="core-container">
    <div class="core-content">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-left">
                <div class="navbar-logo">
                    LOGO
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-suggestions">
                    SUGGESTIONS
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-notifications">
                    NOTIFICATIONS
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>Profiles & Schedules</li>
                    <li>Settings</li>
                    <li>Log Out</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css code:

/***MASTER PAGE***/

```
.core-container
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

.core-content
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.navbar
{
    border: 1px solid red;   
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.navbar-right div
{
    float: right;
}


.navbar-left div
{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-right ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense. What do you mean when you hover over `navbar-left` it has a height of 0px? It works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/BcupG/. I honestly cannot see what your problem is.

Comment: DIVs are the wrong tool for the job. Use a styled unordered list for menus. They make more semantic sense, and they work. See: preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists

Comment: @JoshuaM I think you missed the part where the OP pressed F12, or did that not make sense to you either?

Comment: @Mr Lister: Sorry, I saw his excessive use of caps and must've switched off. Also, I still can't see why any problem is occurring? It renders fine, regardless of the F12.

Comment: @JoshuaM I presume there'd be a problem if the div needed a background colour or something.

Comment: yes tnx guys for your comments. It is shown fine, but if you try again with the code I just inserted it doesn't. Both navbar-right and navbar-left have a 0px height, yet the children inside it are shown OK. I plan to use divs since all children in navbar-left will become dropdown lists!

Comment: You can use a `<ul>` for drop down lists too. http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything in your navbar-left is floating, so its height remains 0. But is that a problem? It looks good on the screen!

Anyway, the quick answer is to append `float:none` to the style for the `clear` class. Make sure you make it specific enough to override the styles for `.navbar-left div` and `navbar-right div` though, like this:

```
.navbar-left .clear, .navbar-right .clear
{
    clear: both;
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: I have done what you told me but everything remains the same. The problem is more clear if you add the code I re-inserted in the question!

Comment: @test OK, I edited. The code above should go where your last style block (for `clear`) goes.

Comment: thank you a lot for your patience. but unfortunately I cannot understand you well. What do you mean by last style block? thank you very much for your time!

Comment: At the end of your CSS, where it starts with `.clear`. The problem is that just `.clear` by itself for a selector isn't specific enough, so the `float:none` wouldn't be picked up. So you do need `.navbar-left .clear, .navbar-right .clear` for a selector.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that your `clear` DIV also have `float` on it because you define **class** like this:

```
.navbar-right div
{
    float: right;
}
```

write like this:

```
.navbar-right .clear
    {
        float: none;
    }
```